# What is the difference between Narayana and Brahman?

Tags: vishnu, brahman, satyanarayana

I understand that deities are One while seeming distinct in our perception of reality. Yet we *do* differentiate between deities (e.g. Hanumān is seen as distinct from Gaṇeśa).

So, before I read that the Bhāgavata Purāṇa states that Nārāyaṇa is Para Brahman I already understood that they are One. But, the statement itself would be unnecessary if everyone already knew they were One. So, how do/did people see Nārāyaṇa and Brahman as distinct?

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. You may understand the concept of Trinity in general term as: Lord Narayana (Vishnu) is Preserver, Lord Brahma is Creator, and Lord Shiva is Destroyer. Now, Brahma and Brahman are two different term. Brahma is Creator while Brahman is the `Ultimate Reality` or `Supreme`. Now there are many sects related to Lord Narayana and Lord Shiva and Lord Brahma. All these are supreme according to their followers. So, these all are referred as Brahman.

Comment: I knew of the Trimurti and understood each part to mean as you have said: creator, preserver, and destroyer. I thought that Brahman was made up of three (or more) parts: Brahma, Vishnu, Shiva. But, doesn't the name (title?) Naranaya mean creator? That would make Vishnu creator **and** sustainer, wouldn't it? Or, do only Vaishnavites call Vishnu as Naranaya?

Comment: But, doesn't the name (title?) Naranaya mean creator? No. Narayana is made up of two word `nAra` means water and `ayana` means residing. So, as a whole `Narayana` means who resides in water. And not only Vaishnavite but everyone call Vishnu as Narayana.

Comment: Shriman Narayana or Lord Vishnu is Bramhan or Paramatma the omnipresent omniscent super soul. Lord Vishnu gave birth to hiranyagarbha or Bramha

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī BrahmA refers to the 4 faced Brahma, who is the creator of the universe, and first born from Brahman. BrahmaN is the inner-self of all beings and the supreme reality. And Narayana is synonymous with Vishnu and Brahman itself. Narayana is the inner-self of Brahma, Shiva, and everyone and everything else. The word "Narayana" etymologically means two things: 1) One who rests on water. OR 2) The resting place of all beings

Comment: "And Narayana is synonymous with Vishnu and Brahman itself." This is the part I'm not understanding.

Comment: Rubellite all gods be Vishnu, Shiva, Devi, Ganesha, Surya all are called Para Brahman. Even though there is difference in them on gross levels, like Vishnu is blue, Shiva is white, Ganesha has elephant head. But on subtle levels they are all one. One Para Brahma.

Comment: Yet, that Supreme Para Brahman is superior and is the ultimate reality. That Para Brahman becomes Vishnu, Shiva, Brahmaa, Devi, Ganesha and all. By meditating and worshipping that Para Brahman only, Vishnu, Shiva, Devi, Brahmaa, Ganesha et cetera have got their status. And Vaishnavas call that Para Brahma as vishnu, Shaivas call It Shiva, Shaaktas call It Devi, Gaanapatya call It Ganesha, and same for other sects. But at the End, the Supreme Formless Para Brahman is the Ultimate reality untainted by any discrepancies and the Supreme Bliss.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī vaishnavas believe that para brahman is sagunam with form, adi shankaracharya believed that Lord Vishnu is ultimately formless. Vishnu is brahman-the distinction comes in beleif if him having form or being formless.

Comment: @AnuragSingh For me, all of those are forms. As you said, there are differences at the gross level. Are there sects which refer to Para Brahman in formless, limitless form?

Comment: There should be, like Advaita sect also refer to formless Para Brahma. In fact Devi Puraana also eulogises Para Brahma that It is the ultimate. And more over, whatever sect we are in , the ultimate will be Para Brahma only. There are several Yogis in himalayan ranges who meditate that Formless Para Brahma. Markandeya Puraana also contains chapters which teach to worship only formless Para Brahma. Vivek Chudamani Text also teach to worship Formless Para Brahma .

Comment: Many Upanishats also teach Para Brahma only. We do not need to be in some sect to worship Para Brahma, and for that matter even the Gods with form. Just think, we are not able to understand even Shiva, Devi, Krishna, Ganesha whom we can interact with, whom we can see, whom we can understand. So to fix mind in that Formless Para Brahma is even hard. I believe Para Brahma Itself has become Shiva, Devi, Vishnu, Ganesha et cetera so that least excelled to at most excelled people can understand Param Brahma.

Comment: @AnuragSingh Please provide this as an answer so I can select it for its wisdom

Comment: But you have named the sources of your info: Devi Puraana, Markandeya Puraana, Vivek Chudamani Text, etc

Comment: Please have a look at other SE. There, every question has many "answers." Some are wrong, but they aren't afraid to try. I feel Hinduism.SE will become worthless without answers.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī The vishNu gAyatri equates nArAyaNa directly with vishNu. And Regarding Vishnu's identity with Brahman, this verse from Vishnu Purana should help: _paramātmā ca sarveṣām ādhāraḥ parameśvaraḥ |
viṣṇur nāmnā sa vedeṣu vedānteṣu ca gīyate ||_ (~Vishnu Purana 6.4.40)

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan So, Viṣnu is not an aspect or manifestation of Brahman, but the totality? I know there must be a reason for using different names in different places, but I cannot understand what it is.

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī Yes, srimannArAyaNa is ParaBrahman, the totality of existence. All names in all places like Sankarshana, Rudra, Hiranyagarbha refer ultimately to srimannArAyaNa.

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan  does RubelliteYakṣī refer to ParaBrahman also?

Comment: @RubelliteYakṣī is a mode or prakara of ParaBrahman

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/77413/discussion-between-lakshminarayanan-and-rubellite-yak).

Comment: Brahman mean God, when you can call one as god is one who is responsible for creation, sustenance, destruction, giver of knowledge, giver of ignorance, one who bounds the jiva in his creation, one who gives moksha, giver of justice. these are the primary of eight action performed by God. that is why he is know by 8 later word.  All action of beings are subset of above eight and are depend entirely on god.. so he is Narayana know by 8 letter word

Comment: The above is given by madva sampradaya saints.. but Narayana have 1000 of meaning, srivasa theertha of uttradhi mut had given 100 such meaning in one of the granthas

Comment: Are you still interested in other answers to this question?

Comment: @yAdRcchika Only to the extent that a good answer could help others. I'll probably write the answer myself. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The confusion between the original question and the Answers & Comments previously given stems from a misunderstanding by the Asker (a younger me). Because things seem distinct by our perceptions even when someone understand all things are foundationally One, there can be confusion between ① the names of (seemingly) differing deities and ② different epithets for the same deity.

Here are two examples:

- In Judaism, ʾĒl ʿElyōn ("God Most High") is understood to be an *epithet* for YHVH, not another *name* for YHVH nor the name of another entity altogether.
- In Shaivism, Trilocana ("Three-eyed") is understood to be an *epithet* for Śiva, not another name or deity. In fact, "śiva" itself was originally an epithet for Rudra.

In a philosophy that describes all things as unified as One epithets can evolve into names. And, when one thing has multiple names it can easily be confused as being multiple things. Nārāyaṇa was an early epithet meaning "(that which) abides (within the) waters."

> The waters are called narah, (for) the waters are, indeed, the offspring of Nara; as they were his first residence (ayana), he thence is named Narayana.

—Manusmṛiti: chapter 1, verse 10

Though this epithet predates the name Viṣṇu, both refer to the same entity.

Thus, the statement, "Nārāyaṇa is Para Brahman" is the same statement as, "Viṣṇu is Para Brahman." I'm not certain "how people saw Nārāyaṇa and Brahman as distinct," but I suspect that the concept of Nārāyaṇa was understood by people before the concept of Para Brahman. I believe so because aspects of reality relating to the elements are always understood by humans before more ideological concepts such as "that which is beyond all descriptions and conceptualisations." People had to understand each concept individually before they could understand them as the same thing.

Comment: While explaining the epithet Nārāyaṇa,  you had stated **Though this epithet predates the name Viṣṇu**.  I don't know the basis for this statement.   As far as I understood,  Nārāyaṇa doesn't appear/refer to Vishnu,  which is an epithead of Almighty in Rig Veda.  If you had come across such mention in Rig Veda, please give reference,  so that I can correct myself.

Comment: Thanks. I'll have to remind myself to look for this reference next time I'm in the mood to research. I cannot recall off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

Trinity of Hinduism are actually three forms of *Eternal Superme God or Sanatan Param Brahman.* Brahma is one of the form of that *Param Brahman* like Vishnu. Kaivalya Upanishad Mantra 8.

> स ब्रह्मा स शिवः सेन्द्रः सोऽक्षरः परमः स्वराट् । स एव विष्णुः स प्राणः स कालोऽग्निः स चन्द्रमाः॥८॥
>
> 8. **He(Superme God/Param Brahman) is Brahma**, he is Siva, he is Indra. He is the imperishable, supreme self illumined Lord. **He alone is Vishnu.** He is the life giving breath. He is time, he is fire, and also the moon.

[image]

The shloka is from [Vishnu Purana.](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/vp/vp036.htm)

> **Thus the one only god,
> Janárddana(Param Brahman), takes the designation of Brahmá, Vishńu, and Śiva**, accordingly as he creates, preserves, or destroys.

Comment: Right. This was all understood when I asked the question. However, even knowing all deities are one in Brahman there are differences between them within the māyā of how we perceive reality.